# Is the elevator disk scheduling algorithm the same as NCQ?

Tags: algorithm, driver, disk

Is there any difference between these two? Both of them has an entry in Wikipedia, but I don't see any difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

NCQ is a mechanism to enqueue multiple requests to a disk for it to handle them in some preferred order.  The classic elevator scheduling algorithm is one possible way to reorder a queue full of I/O requests.  The former is a hardware mechanism tied to a disk, the latter is a software algorithm that may be performed by the OS or the disk.